# Alternativas de views engine para nodejs?

Tags: html, css, node.js

Alternativas que não sejam Jade e similares, procuro saber alternativas que se possam escrever a sintaxe (HTML e CSS) completa?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Além de Jade, já trabalhei com outras duas view engines:

---

- **[ejs](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs)**

Basicamente, o `ejs` processa código JavaScript dentro de tags `<% %>` na sua view. Por exemplo:

```
<div>
    <h1>Você gosta de pudim?</h1>
    <% if (usuario.gostaDePudim) { %>
        <h2>Você é um cara legal!</h2>
    <% } else { %>
        <h2>Você não é legal >:(</h2>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

Assim, caso a variável `usuario.gostaDePudim` seja verdadeira, o seguinte HTML será gerado:

```
<div>
    <h1>Você gosta de pudim?>
    <h2>Você é um cara legal!</h2>
</div>
```

---

- **[eco](https://github.com/sstephenson/eco)**

O `eco` funciona da mesma forma que o `ejs` com as tags `<% %>`, mas utilizando [CoffeeScript](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoffeeScript). O exemplo abaixo usa o mesmo modelo do exemplo de `ejs`:

```
<div>
    <h1>Você gosta de pudim?</h1>
    <% if @usuario.gostaDePudim : %>
        <h2>Você é um cara legal!</h2>
    <% else : %>
        <h2>Você não é legal >:(</h2>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

---

Essa [resposta no Quora](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-node-js-template-engine/answer/Azat-Mardan?srid=oWUv) cita várias outras view engines:

- [atpl](https://github.com/soywiz/atpl.js)
- [dust](https://github.com/akdubya/dustjs)
- [ect](https://github.com/baryshev/ect)
- [haml](https://github.com/visionmedia/haml.js)
- [haml-coffee](https://github.com/9elements/haml-coffee)
- [handlebars](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/)
- [hogan](https://github.com/twitter/hogan.js)
- [jazz](https://github.com/shinetech/jazz)
- [JUST](https://github.com/baryshev/just)
- [liquor](https://github.com/chjj/liquor)
- [mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)
- [QEJS](https://github.com/jepso/QEJS)
- [swig](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig)
- [templayed](http://archan937.github.io/templayed.js/)
- [toffee](https://github.com/malgorithms/toffee)
- [underscore](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore)
- [walrus](https://github.com/jeremyruppel/walrus)

Comment: Uso ejs no express3 más to tomando uma surra pra usar no express4...thanks pela resposta varias fontes :)

Comment: Adicionei links para as páginas do GitHub de cada view engine :)